# On click slide to width 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.slide').animate({
        width: "450px";
        display: block;
    });
});
```

```css
.slide {
    width: 0px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slide"></div>

<button>Slide the div</button>
```

When I click on the button I want `.slide` to appear to the left like a slide.

I already put my width div at `width: 0px`. Then in jQuery this div would get `width: 450px`.

Comment: You can't animate the `display` property.

Comment: Or at least animate the width from 0px to 450px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had some syntax errors within the `animate` the `;` should be a `,` and the `button` had no class so the click event was never executed. Also, you can't animate the `display` property.

Here's the updated snippet:

```js
$('.open-menu').click(function(){

            $('.slide').animate({
                width: "450"
            });

});
```

```css
.slide {
    width: 0px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slide"></div>

<button class="open-menu">Slide the div</button>
```

Comment: @CorentinBranquet if this was the solution for you please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code:

- [Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) won't take care of the `display` property.
- Click handler setup should be wrapped in the [jQuery `ready` function](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).
- Button needs the class `open-menu`.
- Object properties in `animate` argument shouldn't end with semicolons.

See below for a working example.

```js
$(function () {
    $('.open-menu').click(function(){
        $('.slide').animate({
            width: "450px"
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.slide {
    width: 0px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="open-menu">Slide the div</button>
<div class="slide"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't maintain the button to the right of the div. Use inline-block in both elements

Comment: @sailens Good point. I updated it to just leave the elements with their normal document flow.